# Run application for filelist in a directory (Windows CMD)

Tags: batch-file, cmd, filelist

I have a built-in application called app.exe
This application is decoding the .csv files present in the same folder and save the decoded data in a new sub-folder. For example, for a file called "data_1.csv", I run the application with the following CMD

```
app data_1.csv
```

I have a large amount of file in this directory, and I would like to run automatically all of them through the application.

I tried different things:

- to merge all of the files to decode : this is too heavy (hundreds of GB)
- to do a batch file: the decoder is decoding the .bat file...
- to use

  for %f in (.*) do app %f

It is crashing the computer because the app is going through itself...

Is there a way to create a simple file list of the .csv files and to run this built-in application?

Thanks

Comment: looks like "for %f in (*.txt) do app %f" should work :)

Comment: Start using `for %f in (*.csv) do @echo @app %f` to see command behaviour. Remove `@echo` as soon as debugged.

Comment: Note to double the `%` signs in `for` loop variables (`%%f` instead of `%f`) in batch files...

Comment: What does "the app is going through itself..." mean? Can you post error messages? What happens when you use `for %f in (*.txt) do (app "%f")`